# Twig render does not take 2 arrays

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I have Twig installed and im playing around with it a bit.
I have two arrays the first holds site configurations like the name,title,keywords and another one that hold userdata when the user is logged in. 
The render function looks like this:

```
echo $pg->render('user_homepage.twig', $this->siteSettings,array("email"=>$_SESSION["email"]));
```

When I wirte

```
Welcome, {{ email }}
```

it only shows

```
Welcome,
```

Site settings are available but not the email.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sticking those in one array

```
echo $pg->render('user_homepage.twig', array_merge($this->siteSettings,['email'=>$_SESSION["email"]]));
```